# How to increase label value with stepper?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uistepper

I have `priceLabel` which has `Food`'s property `price` . I want to increase this `priceLabel` with it is first value. For example `priceLabel`'s first value is 15.00 and when user tap stepper and first value increase with it is own value. (e.g. 2 tap to increase `15 + 15 = 30`)

I think like `stepper.stepValue = priceLabel.text`

Here is my codes

```
import UIKit
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var foodTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var foodSubTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var foodPiece: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var foodPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var drinkPicker: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var constantPieceLabel: UILabel!

var menuPieceStepper : UIStepper!
var drinkPickerView = UIPickerView()

var selectDrinkType: [String] = []
var detailFoodName : [String] = []
var detailFoodPrice : [Double] = [0.0]

var constPiece = 0

let foods = Food(name: ["Hamburger big mac",
                           "Patates",
                           "Whopper",
                           "Steakhouse"], price: [15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 30.0])
```

I need to use `@IBAction` or `#selector` ?

```
@IBAction func foodPieceStepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    foodPrice.text = Double(sender.value).description
}

@objc func foodPieceChangeStepper() {

    foodPrice.text = "\(menuPieceStepper.value)"
}

//TODO:- Add to basket
@IBAction func addBasket(_ sender: Any) {

        let destinationVC = MyCartViewController()

        destinationVC.fromDetailFoodNames = foods.name
        destinationVC.fromDetailFoodPrices = foods.price

    dismiss(animated: true)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if(segue.identifier == "addToCartSegue") {
        if let addToCartVC = segue.destination as? MyCartViewController {


            addToCartVC.fromDetailFoodNames = foods.name
            addToCartVC.fromDetailFoodPrices = foods.price

    }
   }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    menuPieceStepper = UIStepper()
    menuPieceStepper.value = 0.0
    menuPieceStepper.minimumValue = 0.0
    menuPieceStepper.maximumValue = 30.0
    menuPieceStepper.stepValue = foods.price.first!
    menuPieceStepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(foodPieceChangeStepper), for: .valueChanged)

    foodPieceChangeStepper()

    drinkPickerView.delegate = self
    drinkPicker.inputView = drinkPickerView
    selectDrinkType = ["Ayran", "Kola", "Su", "Fanta", "Şalgam", "Sprite"]

    foodTitle.text = detailFoodName.description
    foodPrice.text = detailFoodPrice.description

    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.title = "Sipariş Detayı"

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false

}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Selector / IBAction has no difference

```
@objc func foodPieceChangeStepper() { 
  let res = menuPieceStepper.value * foods.price.first!
  foodPrice.text = "\(res)"
}
```

---

Then you should set step value to

```
menuPieceStepper.stepValue = 1.0
```

and inside the stepper action

```
menuPieceStepper.value * currentPiecePrice
```

Comment: I do not want to increase with constant value like `15.0`. I need to put my `Food(price:[15.0]`price value. `menuPieceStepper.value * menuPieceStepper.value`. Yours did not change value

Comment: Food prices coming from `Food` models constant `price array`. When I click to `MainViewController`'s table view cell, price pass to my `DetailViewController`' priceLabel. `DetailViewController` priceLabel outlet dynamically change which cell is selected on `MainVC`. This case is add to my basket products with piece. One piece is 20.00$ and when stepper increased 2 price is 40.00$

Comment: Im do not understand "and inside the stepper action" part and  `menuPieceStepper.value * currentPiecePrice
 `. Already changed res constant with ` menuPieceStepper.value * menuPieceStepper.value`. Why we change stepper action again to `menuPieceStepper.value * currentPiecePrice` ?

Comment: according  to your min/maxValue stepper values then you will get values from 0 --- 30  that increases by step value , so you need to multiply it with the current detail price sended from mainVC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189592/discussion-between-emre-degirmenci-and-sh-khan).

Comment: I am so sorry I can not use `currentPiecePrice` in my own code

Comment: it's = `foods.price.first!`

Comment: Should I add these `menuPieceStepper.value * currentPiecePrice` to new `var` or `let` ? So I am getting this warning `Result of operator '*' is unused`